# System.String extension member in F# for Chars

Tags: f#

I have gone through the documentation and source code for System.String. I can see that the default indexer is defined with this[int index] and that the alias "Chars" is used. I want to extend it by writing the below code.

```
type System.String with
    member self.Chars (boolean:bool) = if boolean then self.[0] else self.[1]

printfn "%c" ("abc".[false])
printfn "%c" ("abc".Chars(false))
```

The reason why is because I have seen other articles and code snippets pointing to the idea that I would have this ability. I am now trying to test it out. I also noticed that System.String is defined as Sealed.

```
[<Sealed>]
```

I have been doing many searches and looking at sites like fssnip.net and Tomas P's articles and here on Stackoverflow. What am I missing?

Comment: Which problem do you experience?

Comment: The extension method will never have priority over the compiled property. You can try renaming your extension method to something else like `FirstChar` or something like that

Comment: @MarkSeemann : Hello, the error from the compiler is Error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    int    but here has type    bool (FS0001)

Comment: @Ringil : I was hoping that the different signature would allow it to co-exist with the existing method. I do not want to redefine Chars(int), I want to have an additional Chars(bool) that would resolve. Is there any articles that point to language or runtime issues limiting me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is because Chars is an alias to a property and not a method itself. Extension methods seem to not be possible on properties.

Even though it is a get with a parameter, there would had to of been a generic version created and that would likely need to point to a method that I could create my constrained version from. @Ringil led me in the right direction. Thank you. Good day.